# Netlify CMS - save data to project root (e.g. `__dirname`)

Tags: yaml, gatsby, netlify-cms

I'm using Netlify CMS within a Gatsby Theme. Here is an example of my project structure:

```
root/
  themes/
    gatsby-theme-example/
      pages/
        index.js
      static/
        admin/
          config.yml
      gatsby-config.js
      package.json
  sites/
    example-theme-site/
      data/
        content.md
      gatsby-config.js
      package.json
  package.json
```

More info:

- `gatsby-theme-example` uses [gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-netlify-cms/), with the `config.yml` file located at `root/themes/gatsby-theme-example/static/admin/config.yml`
- `gatsby-theme-example` and `example-theme-site` are connected via [yarn workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/), however I intend to publish `gatsby-theme-example` to npm once it's fully developed so users can install it as a package. `example-theme-site` is only used for development testing purposes.

This means that:

1. Running `yarn workspace example-theme-site develop` will run `gatsby develop` for `example-theme-site`
2. Users can then visit `http://localhost:8000/admin` and access Netlify CMS. Once logged in, this will load Netlify CMS using the config file located within `root/themes/gatsby-theme-example/static/admin/config.yml`

The next step I want to occur after this is:

- Users add content to Netlify CMS
- When saved/published, this new data is saved under the `root/sites/example-theme-site/data` directory.

This is the issue I'm having difficulty with, as the config file is located in `gatsby-theme-example` however I want the data to save to `example-theme-site`. I'm not sure how to make the path relative to the root directory without hard-coding it in.

I see that I can specify the location to save the data [under `file` or `folder` in the `config.yml`](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/collection-types), however since `config.yml` is a .yml file, I don't see how I can use something like `__dirname` to specify the correct directory. The only option I can see would be to hard-code in the file path (e.g. `file: "../../sites/example-theme-site/data/content.md"`) while in development, then change it so it's relative to `node_modules` just before I publish the theme to npm.

Is there any other more appropriate solution here?

Comment: I've been dealing with this the past week. Were you ever able to resolve this? I noticed this had been posted over a year ago.

Answer (score 0):

The location of the config file in your repo doesn't matter - the config file is processed in the browser. All paths in your config are always relative to the repo root.